# How do I get only horizontal scrollbar if content margin overflows card?

Tags: css, angular-material

I want only horizontal scrollbar on a long horizontal div of `mat-card`s

Even with `overflow-y` set to 'visible', the vertical scrollbar does not go away. A quick fix was to set the div's `padding-bottom` to 2em, however, I'm searching for an explanation for the problem as well as a more elegant solution, if available.

[This is how it currently is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6sfyv)

I expect the `div.mess` to have only a horizontal scrollbar. An added bonus would be to have the `margin-bottom` of `img[mat-card-image]` within the `mat-card`, but is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
.mess{
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden
}
```

This code will hidden your vertical scroll.

Scroll happens when you try fill in a box more than its width or height so you can simply hidden the vertical, horizontal scroll or set parent height to auto:

```
.example-card{
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to make any modifications to whatever's happening vertically. That includes `overflow-y=hidden`, which I believe clips the overflowing content. If it overflows, let it (which is the reason for the `overflow-y=visible` attempt in my demo, although its does absolutely nothing). Just delete everything from `.mess` css class to see what it looks like, then imagine applying **just** a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: key to writing a good code in css is to never give height to parents because it can lead to vertical scroll if you take a look at your images you can see they are also overflowing from `mat-card`  so first of all you must remove parent height and let it be auto second you should set image width , height in `img[mat-card-image]{}` or just remove it to give default height ,width you can also use `object-fit:` property on images then you can see 32px space between image and `example-card` horizontal scroll which is happening because of 2 `padding-bottom:16px` if you remove them you are good to go